# Aumentar TextView cada cierta cantidad de segundos

Tags: android, android-studio, textview, timer

Pues eso mismo, quiero saber si se pueden aumentar la cantidad de `TextView` cada 5 (cinco) segundos por ejemplo.

**Código:**

```
historia = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.cuerpoProgramado);
```

**Timer de cinco segundos:**

```
private final static int TIEMPO = 5000;
public void timer(){
        handler.postDelayed(new Runnable() {
            @Override
            public void run() {
                handler.postDelayed(this, TIEMPO);
            }
        }, TIEMPO);
    }
```

Ahora, lo que quiero saber es si se pueden incremetar los `TextView` cada cinco segundos y que cada uno venga con un texto diferente pero sin que se borre el primero.
A modo "ilustrativo"":

```
textview.setText("hola")
timer()
textview.setText("¿Cómo estas?")
```

**Resultado:**

```
hola
¿Cómo estas?
```

Comment: y de donde tomaras los textos diferentes

Comment: Se puede solo guarda el String en una variable y concatena la nueva palabra, es como sumar strings. Para salto de linea es "\n". Seria algo asi "Hola \n" + "¿Cómo estas?"

Comment: Los tomaré de distintas variables `Strings`, lo que no quiero es que se acumulen en un mismo `TextView`, sino que vayan apareciendo varios `TextView` conforme a la cantidad de variables que tenga @Elenasys

Comment: No busco un salto de línea, busco que se añadan más `String` conforme a la cantidad de variables de texto que tenga @OsAndNoTi

Comment: es que comentaste esto : "es como sumar strings. Para salto de linea es "\n". Seria algo asi "Hola \n" + "¿Cómo estas?" , pero si quieres agregar varios TextView, debes tomar en cuenta que en algún momento podrías tener problemas con memoria al agregar programaticamente un numero considerable de vistas

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Puedes definir los mensajes a mostrar en un array:

```
String[] mensajes =  {"Hola", "Como estas?", "Franqo", "es un gran día!"};
int counter;
```

y mediante un `handler` llamar cada elemento en el array para mostrarlo en tu `TextView`:

```
final Handler myHandler = new Handler();
myHandler.postDelayed(new Runnable() {
    @Override
    public void run() {
        if(counter < mensajes.length) {
            textview.setText(textview.getText().toString() + "\n" + mensajes[counter]);
            myHandler.postDelayed(this, 5000); //5 segundos
            counter++;
        }
    }
}, 1000);
```